# Flask UnitTests accessing wrong URI

Tags: python, flask

I have written some unit tests/integration tests for flask using python unittest. I am broadly using the example code written out here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-unit-testing-legacy

These tests used to run perfectly but now I have just tried to run them again and am running up against an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'cloud-sql' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)")
```

(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Obviously this is telling me that it's trying to connect to cloud-sql and can't (this is the correct DNS name after deployment). However I have configured a different URI for testing.

This is what my test_web_api.py looks like:

```
import os
import unittest
import json
from flask import url_for
from requests.auth import _basic_auth_str
from app import app, db
from app.models import User, UserToken, UserRoles, RolesList, BandwidthResults

TEST_DB = 'test.db'


class API_Tests(unittest.TestCase):

    ############################
    #### setup and teardown ####
    ############################
    test_admin_password = 'testpass'
    test_admin_user = 'admin'
    api_token = None
    # executed prior to each test

    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {}
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
            os.path.join(app.config['BASEDIR'], TEST_DB)
        app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1 localhost.dev'
        self.client = app.test_client(use_cookies=True)
        self.app_context = app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        
        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()

        # # Create admin user
        user = User(username=self.test_admin_user, email='test@example.com')
        user.set_password(self.test_admin_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        # Give admin user admin roles
        admin_role = RolesList(name='admin')
        db.session.add(admin_role)
        db.session.commit()
        user_role = UserRoles(role=RolesList.query.first().id,
                              user_id=User.query.filter_by(username=self.test_admin_user).first().id)
        db.session.add(user_role)
        # Generate an API token
        db.session.commit()
        response = self.client.get(url_for('api.token_token_api'), headers={
                                   "Authorization": _basic_auth_str(self.test_admin_user, self.test_admin_password)},
                                   query_string={'expiry': 300})
        self.api_token = json.loads(response.data)['token']

    # executed after each test
    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()
        pass

###########################
#### tests-integration ####
###########################

    def test_01_api_token_get_auth(self):
        response = self.client.get(url_for('api.token_token_api'), headers={
                                   "Authorization": _basic_auth_str(self.test_admin_user, self.test_admin_password)})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertIsNotNone(json.loads(response.data)['token'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is what my `__init__.py` looks like for 'app'

```
from flask import Flask

from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_principal import Principal
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.flask import FlaskIntegration

app = Flask(__name__)

from app.tasks.init import make_celery  # noqa: E402

app.config.from_object(Config)

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="",
    integrations=[FlaskIntegration()],
    environment=app.config['SENTRY_ENV'],
    release=app.config['SENTRY_RELEASE'],

)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'], async_mode='gevent', cors_allowed_origins="")
ma = Marshmallow(app)
celery = make_celery(app)
root_path = app.root_path
principal = Principal(app)

from app import routes, models  # noqa: E402,F401
from app.apis import blueprint as api  # noqa: E402

app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api/1')
```

I am at a loss to why. There have been no changes to the code base, everything runs in a docker image, with a pinned version, all the packages have pinned versions in requirements.txt. Grateful for any hints.

Comment: The issue is that some of the code that you have in the global scope (which runs before the `startUp()` method, must be trying to access the database. Look at the stack trace of the error to determine from where this access comes.

Comment: In the stack trace it was actually the 'db.session.commit()' that was causing the error. So I trawled through the comments on your blog post and found the 'db.session.remove()'. Running this before the db.drop_all() seemed to reset the session so it picks up the 'test' settings. The tests are now passing as well. Thanks a lot for the comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing the session after updating the app configuration (this was in my setUp() function)

Notice the db.session.remove()
This seems to clear the ?current database session that still was trying to access the database on the old values.

```
def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ENGINE_OPTIONS'] = {}
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
            os.path.join(app.config['BASEDIR'], TEST_DB)
        app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1 localhost.dev'
        self.client = app.test_client(use_cookies=True)
        self.app_context = app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

        db.session.remove()

        db.drop_all()
        db.create_all()
        # Create admin user
        user = User(username=self.test_admin_user, email='test@example.com')
        user.set_password(self.test_admin_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        # Give admin user admin roles
        admin_role = RolesList(name='admin')
        db.session.add(admin_role)
        db.session.commit()
        user_role = UserRoles(role=RolesList.query.first().id,
                              user_id=User.query.filter_by(username=self.test_admin_user).first().id)
        db.session.add(user_role)
        # Generate an API token
        db.session.commit()
        response = self.client.get(url_for('api.token_token_api'), headers={
                                   "Authorization": _basic_auth_str(self.test_admin_user, self.test_admin_password)},
                                   query_string={'expiry': 300})
        self.api_token = json.loads(response.data)['token']
```